# How to make chrome.scripting.executeScript run same file again?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vite

I am using `executeScript` to open a html file (sidebar) when clicking on my extension icon. This is the code:

```
import toggleExtension from './toggleExtension.ts?script'

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT }, tabs => {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {
          tabId: tabs[0].id as number,
        },
        files: [toggleExtension],
      })
  })
})
```

I can make it work with the `func` parameter, but I would like to reuse the same code for other html files. However this only executes the file on the first run, and subsequent clicks run `executeScript` successfully but the file is not run again.

`toggleExtension` file:

```
const createIframe = (pageUrl: string, id: string) => {
  const iframeEl = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframeEl.id = id
  iframeEl.setAttribute(
    'style',
    `
      z-index: 9999999999;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      border: 0;
    `
  )
  iframeEl.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(pageUrl)
  iframeEl.allow = 'clipboard-write'
  return iframeEl
}

const togglePanel = (mountId: string, htmlPath: string) => {
  const dialog = document.getElementById(mountId)
  if (dialog) {
    dialog.parentElement?.removeChild(dialog)
  } else {
    const iframeEl = createIframe(htmlPath, mountId)
    document.body.appendChild(iframeEl)
  }
}

togglePanel('extension-sidebar-id', 'pages/sidebar.html')
```

Comment: `files` needs a name of the file inside a string, not a module name. Make a separate entry in your build config for this file and don't import it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am using vite, so that variable is actually a string (I am importing with ?script). It translates to something like "/assets/toggleExtension.[hash].js". The first run works fine, so the path must be correct

Comment: I think you need to change the title and add tags.

Comment: In that case the code seems correct. Use devtools to set breakpoints and debug the code.